# How to create boost subgraph with setS vertices list?

Tags: c++, boost, graph

The following code has errors:

> ```
> AAA.cpp:23:15:   required from here
>    .../boost/include/boost/graph/subgraph.hpp:333:5: error: static assertion failed: (!is_same<edge_index_type,
>    boost::detail::error_property_not_found>::value)
>
> AAA.cpp:27:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘add_vertex(foo(int, char**)::<anonymous enum>, Graph&)’
>
> AAA.cpp:27:21: note: candidates are:
>    .../boost/include/boost/graph/subgraph.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::subgraph<Graph>::subgraph(boost::subgraph<Graph>::vertices_size_type,
>    const graph_property_type&) [with Graph =
>    boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::setS, boost::directedS,
>    boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::no_property,
>    boost::setS>; boost::subgraph<Graph>::vertices_size_type = long
>    unsigned int; boost::subgraph<Graph>::graph_property_type =
>    boost::no_property]’:
> ```

```
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/subgraph.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>

int foo(int,char*[])
{
    using namespace boost;
    typedef subgraph< 
        adjacency_list<
            setS, 
            setS, 
            directedS,
            no_property,
            no_property,
            no_property, // graph prop
            setS // edgelist
            > 
        > Graph;

    const int N = 6;
    Graph G0(N);
    enum { A, B, C, D, E, F}; 

    Graph& G1 = G0.create_subgraph();
    add_vertex(C, G1); // global vertex C becomes local A1 for G1

    return 0;
}
```

If I changed setS to vecS for the vertices list, it can be compiled.
How to create boost subgraph with setS vertices list?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it doesn't compile with `vecS` for the VertexContainer:

> To create a graph and subgraphs, first create the root graph object. Here we use adjacency_list as the underlying graph implementation. The underlying graph type is required to have vertex_index and edge_index internal properties, so we add an edge index property to the adjacency list. (**[docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/subgraph.html)**)

So let's add things. Now it compiles:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a14361e082dbbfc4)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/subgraph.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost;
    using containerS = vecS;
    typedef subgraph< adjacency_list<containerS, containerS, directedS,
            property<vertex_index_t, size_t>,
            property<edge_index_t, size_t>
        >
    > Graph;

    const int N = 6;
    Graph G0(N);
    enum { A, B, C, D, E, F}; 

    Graph& G1 = G0.create_subgraph();
    Graph::vertex_descriptor CG1 = add_vertex(G1);
    Graph::vertex_descriptor EG1 = add_vertex(G1);

    add_edge(CG1, EG1, G1);

    print_graph(G0);
    std::cout << "SUBGRAPH:\n";
    print_graph(G1);
}
```

Prints

```
0 --> 
1 --> 
2 --> 
3 --> 
4 --> 
5 --> 
6 --> 7 
7 --> 
SUBGRAPH:
0 --> 1 
1 -->
```

### Using `setS`

Frankly, although the documentation suggests indirectly that something like `listS` or `setS` could be chosen I honestly don't think this can work.

The problem seems to be how `local_to_global` and `m_global_vertex` have been implemented.

This might be an artificial limitation/unimplemented feature. you might want to raise this question at the developer list/Trac issues.

Comment: What is 'the developer list/Trac issues'? Where can I post such an issue?

Comment: Googled: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10165 and http://www.boost.org/community/groups.html

Answer (score 0):

I found 
1) setS could be used as outedges and edges lists
2) vertex_index and edge_index must be defined
3) we could also use bundled properties in the meanwhile

The follow code works.

```
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/subgraph.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>

int foo(int,char*[])
{
    using namespace boost;
  typedef adjacency_list_traits<vecS, vecS, directedS> Traits;

  struct EEE {
      int p;
  };

  struct VVV {
      int p;
  };

  typedef subgraph< 
    adjacency_list<
        setS, 
        vecS, 
        directedS,
        property<vertex_color_t, int, VVV>,
        property<edge_index_t, int, EEE>,
        no_property, // graph prop
        setS // edgelist
        > 
    > Graph;

 const int N = 6;
 Graph G0(N);
 enum { A, B, C, D, E, F};     // for conveniently refering to vertices in G0

 Graph& G1 = G0.create_subgraph();
 Graph& G2 = G0.create_subgraph();
 enum { A1, B1, C1 };          // for conveniently refering to vertices in G1
  enum { A2, B2 };              // for conveniently refering to vertices in G2

  add_vertex(C, G1); // global vertex C becomes local A1 for G1
  add_vertex(E, G1); // global vertex E becomes local B1 for G1
  add_vertex(F, G1); // global vertex F becomes local C1 for G1

  add_vertex(A, G2); // global vertex A becomes local A1 for G2
  add_vertex(B, G2); // global vertex B becomes local B1 for G2

  add_edge(A, B, G0);
  add_edge(B, C, G0);
  add_edge(B, D, G0);
  add_edge(E, B, G0);
  add_edge(E, F, G0);
  add_edge(F, D, G0);

  add_edge(A1, C1, G1); // (A1,C1) is subgraph G1 local indices for (C,F).

  Graph::vertex_iterator vi, vi_end;
  VVV vvv;
  EEE eee;
  for (tie(vi, vi_end) = vertices(G0); vi != vi_end; ++vi) {
     G0[*vi].p = 42;
     auto e = add_edge(*vi, *vi, G0);
     G0[e.first] = eee;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [sehe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85371/sehe) has pointed out, we can easily implement `local_to_global` like:

```
vertex_descriptor local_to_global(vertex_descriptor u_local) const
    { return is_root() ? u_local : m_global_vertex[get(get(vertex_index, m_graph), u_local)]; }
```

In my situation, I've got to add and remove vertices while keeping vertex iterator/descriptor stable so I need to use `listS` for my vertex descriptor. It's weird that boost does not seem to be fixed on this.